# Is there a formula to extract the real part of a complex vector?

Tags: complex-numbers, vector-spaces

For a complex number $z\in \mathbb{C}$, the formulas for the real part and the imaginary part the well-known formula:

$$
\Re[z]=\frac{z+\overline{z}}{2}\\
\Im[z]=\frac{z-\overline{z}}{2i}
$$

What is the equivalent for complex vectors? Let $\mathbf{z}\in\mathbb{C}^n$, for example

$$
\mathbf{z}=(a+ib,c+id,\dots)
$$

An obvious definition is component-by-component aplication: $\Re[\mathbf{z}]=(\Re[a+ib],\Re[c+id],\dots)$.

However, I was hoping that for specific values of $n$, such as $n=2$ or $n=3$ there could be fancier definitions involving the determinant or the cross product, or other products?

---

The problem I am running into with the component-by-component definition is that studying the invariance group becomes a struggle. For example, it should be relatively easy to show that

$$
f[\mathbf{v}]=\Re[\mathbf{v}]^T\Re[\mathbf{z}]
$$

should be the orthogonal invariance group: $O^TO=I$.

$$
\begin{align}
f[\mathbf{Mv}]&=\Re[M\mathbf{v}]^T\Re[M\mathbf{z}]\\
&=\Re[\pmatrix{m_{00} & m_{01}\\m_{10}&m_{11}}\pmatrix{a+ib\\c+id}]^T\Re[\pmatrix{m_{00} & m_{01}\\m_{10}&m_{11}}\pmatrix{a+ib\\c+id}]\\
&=\pmatrix{\Re[m_{00}(a+ib)+m_{10}(c+id)]\\\Re[m_{10}(a+ib)+m_{11}(c+id)]}^T\pmatrix{\Re[m_{00}(a+ib)+m_{10}(c+id)]\\\Re[m_{10}(a+ib)+m_{11}(c+id)]}\\
&=\Re[m_{00}(a+ib)+m_{10}(c+id)]^2+\Re[m_{10}(a+ib)+m_{11}(c+id)]^2\\\
&=\frac{1}{4}[(m_{00}(a+ib)+m_{10}(c+id))+\overline{m_{00}(a+ib)+m_{10}(c+id)}]^2+\frac{1}{4}[(m_{10}(a+ib)+m_{11}(c+id))+\overline{m_{10}(a+ib)+m_{11}(c+id)}]^2\\
&=\frac{1}{4}[(m_{00}(a+ib)+m_{10}(c+id))+\overline{m_{00}(a+ib)}+\overline{m_{10}(c+id)}]^2+\frac{1}{4}[(m_{10}(a+ib)+m_{11}(c+id))+\overline{m_{10}(a+ib)}+\overline{m_{11}(c+id)}]^2\\
&=\frac{1}{4}[(m_{00}(a+ib)+m_{10}(c+id))+\overline{(a+ib)}\overline{m_{00}}+\overline{(c+id)}\overline{m_{10}}]^2+\frac{1}{4}[(m_{10}(a+ib)+m_{11}(c+id))+\overline{(a+ib)}\overline{m_{10}}+\overline{(c+id)}\overline{m_{11}}]^2\\
&=\frac{1}{4}[(m_{00}(a+ib)+m_{10}(c+id))+(a-ib)\overline{m_{00}}+(c-id)\overline{m_{10}}]^2+\frac{1}{4}[(m_{10}(a+ib)+m_{11}(c+id))+(a-ib)\overline{m_{10}}+(c-id)\overline{m_{11}}]^2\\
&=\frac{1}{4}[m_{00}a+m_{00}ib+m_{10}c+m_{10}id+a\overline{m_{00}}-ib\overline{m_{00}}+c\overline{m_{10}}-id\overline{m_{10}}]^2+\frac{1}{4}[m_{10}a+m_{10}ib+m_{11}c+m_{11}id+a\overline{m_{10}}-ib\overline{m_{10}}+c\overline{m_{11}}-id\overline{m_{11}}]^2\\
&=\frac{1}{4}[a(m_{00}+\overline{m_{00}})+ib(m_{00}-\overline{m_{00}})+c(m_{10}+\overline{m_{10}})+id(m_{10}-\overline{m_{10}})]^2+\frac{1}{4}[a(m_{10}+\overline{m_{10}})+id(m_{10}-\overline{m_{10}})+c(m_{11}+\overline{m_{11}})+id(m_{11}-\overline{m_{11}})]^2\\
&=\frac{1}{4}[a\Re[m_{00}]+ib\Im[m_{00}]+c\Re[m_{10}]+id\Im[m_{10}]]^2+\frac{1}{4}[a\Re[m_{10}]+id\Im[m_{10}]+c\Re[m_{11}]+id\Im[m_{11}]]^2
\end{align}
$$

getting quite verbose...

Comment: *Eventually* you need to use maps which are not holomorphic (and therefore not polynomial), if you want real parts to pop out.

Comment: If you allow component-wise conjugation of vectors, then $(\mathbb{z} + \overline{\mathbb{z}})/2$ still works.

Comment: @JordanMitchellBarrett Actually, I think I just figure it out: its $2\Re[\mathbf{z}]=\mathbf{z}+((\mathbf{z})^*)^T$, where $z^*$ is the conjugate transpose, and $z^T$ is the transpose.